# Two ASP.net applications reading/writing from the same folder

Tags: iis, vs-web-application-project

We have two asp.net web applications (Two asp web projects in one solution)
Both are hosted on IIS. Both apps expose WCF services.
Those services read and write files to the file system. In each service, we determine where to read and write files from using :

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".")
```

So in this way, each service writes and read from the folder of it's web app.
We want the services to read and write from the same place (We want this to happen in development and production ).

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, define the same path in web.config of both web applications. Use the defined path instead of getting Server.MapPath(".").

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Path" value="c:\\somefolder\\"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

C#:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]
```

Comment: But in production, when we upload the apps to an iis hoster, we won't be able to do this